# Inheritance information from ctags for Ruby

Tags: ruby, ctags

How can I get class and module inheritance information from ctags for Ruby?

I tried the `--fields=+i` option but it does not seem to produce `inherits:` in the tags file.

I could get this info for C++ and Java.

Comment: If the input code is simple, Universal ctags can fill the inherits: field:
```
$ cat /tmp/foo.rb 
class A
end 

class B < A
  def doSomething
    print("do something")
  end
end

$ ~/bin/ctags --version
Universal Ctags 5.9.0(cbdc5c4b6), Copyright (C) 2015-2022 
....
$ ~/bin/ctags -o - --fields=+i /tmp/foo.rb 
A /tmp/foo.rb /^class A$/;" c
B /tmp/foo.rb /^class B < A$/;" c inherits:A
doSomething /tmp/foo.rb /^  def doSomething$/;" f class:B
```